# Setting Up Multiple Monitors in Windows 7 Span over or stretched wallpapers?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

As many professionals do, I use as a primary work PC a laptop, which usually remains docked to a desktop setup including a large monitor and full-size keyboard. How to set up live wallpapers w/o any 3rd party tool. Appreciated the answers.

Comment: In simple - Live Motion” - Animated Desktop Wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "live".

If you are "stretching" the desktop across multiple monitors, you only need to hit the "print screen" key and the captured screen image will be the size of the required desktop wallpaper size in pixels. If I recall correctly, if the resolutions of the monitors differ, you will get black bars on the portion of the image which is on the smaller of the two. Basically, the image has the pixel height of the largest resolution and the pixel width of the sum of all widths. (e.g. 2x 1080p monitors will have a desktop size of 1080 px high x 3840 px wide; a 1024 x 768 monitor mixed with a, 800x600 monitor should have a desktop size of 768 high x 1824 wide, and there would be a smaller "live area" of 600hx800w on whichever "half" of the image aligns with the smaller monitor.)

In PS, you need only create a new file after capture and it will fill in the pixel dimensions based upon the clipboard image size. If not, you can start with the formula above and test.

You set your wallpaper to center, no zoom nor stretch.

(note: Windows allows you to make vertical adjustments to the monitors relative to each other, I frankly cannot recall if you need to take this into account or if it is handled automatically)

Comment: What you don't understand LIVE means - The application works as a wallpaper – providing the background image for the home screen—but also works as a conventional application since it can provide user-interaction with the touch screen (allowing the image to change dynamically, for example) and access other hardware and software features!